# how to conditionally join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join, inner-join

I have two tables.

"mw_user" table which looks like this (I have only 4 records as I'm testing.)
[image: user table image]

I also have a "mw_user_selections" table that is populated by an application. for test I have two records in here but eventually more records will end up here.

[image: user_selection_criteria table image]

Now what I'm trying to accomplish is group my users into the specific selection mw_user_selections group. So if you look at the table, I can see that that for Rule1, only RANK_CODE and SUB_SERVICE_LINE_CODE are specified so only Mark Strong matches.
For the second Rule2 I have COUNTRY_CODE and SUB_SERVICE_LINE_CODE populated. So only Mathew Perry and Dwane Johnson would match. So the output I'm looking for will be something like this (first column is the headers. comma denotes new column. GroupName comes from User_Selection_Name column. UserName comes from sAMAccountName column.)

[image]

Because in the "mw_user_selections" all of the upper case named columns are the criteria but some of them can be NULL. for example, I can have another entry in "mw_user_selections" as Rule3 where I chose to put COUNTRY_CODE=US and RANK_CODE=64 and keep all other columns NULL. In that case my query should output the above plus this:

[image]

So I cannot figure out how I will join on multiple columns and get results that I want. Can anyone please help? I appreciate any guidance you can give. Thank you.

```
SELECT
    US.user_selection_name AS 'GROUP_NAME'
    , <?? where to get the other column from> as UserName
FROM
    [dbo].[mw_user_selections] US
    Inner JOIN [dbo].[mw_users] U1 ON US.COUNTRY_CODE = U1.country_code
    Inner JOIN [dbo].[mw_users] U2 ON US.GEO_AREA = U2.geo_area
    Inner JOIN [dbo].[mw_users] U3 ON US.LOCATION_CODE = U3.location_code
    inner join [dbo].[mw_users] U4 ON US.RANK_CODE = u4.rank_code
    inner join [dbo].[mw_users] U5 ON US.LEGAL_ENTITY = u5.legal_entity
    inner join [dbo].[mw_users] U6 ON US.BU_CODE = u6.bu_code
    inner join [dbo].[mw_users] U7 ON US.SERVICE_LINE_CODE = u7.service_line_code
    inner join [dbo].[mw_users] U8 ON US.SUB_SERVICE_LINE_CODE = u8.sub_service_line_code
```

Here is the code I started with but this is not getting me the result I want.

Comment: I cant see any link between the tables, unless I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: I agree with @WhatsThePoint but please provide the code you have tried so far, we are not here to simply provide solutions, we are here to help you work through yours.

Comment: I don't find any "RABK_CODE", "SUB_SERVICE_LINE_CODE"

Comment: Also in your expected output screenshot you mention a rule3, that is not included in your sample data

Comment: I mis typed. its RANK_CODE not RABK_CODE sorry

Comment: I added the sql statement but I'm lost as to how to accomplish what I want.

Comment: There is no link between the tables. They are independent from each there. There is no FK relationship.

Comment: @whatsthepoint - yes I was giving an example that if I add Rule3 into the critieria table, then my out put should look like the second one.

Comment: If the requirement would be to get users based on 1 rule. Then that this could probably be solved best via Dynamic Sql. But if it's for every rule, I'm guessing it'll be one complicated ON clause for 1 JOIN.

Comment: Hi. Please read & act on [mcve]. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what can't be given in text.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with only 1 JOIN.
But because it has to consider all those nullable setting values, the ON clause for that JOIN will become big.

**For example:**

```
SELECT 
 s.user_selection_name AS GroupName, 
 u.sAMAccountName AS UserName
FROM [dbo].[mw_users] AS u  
JOIN [dbo].[mw_user_selections] AS s 
  ON (s.COUNTRY_CODE IS NULL OR s.COUNTRY_CODE = u.country_code) 
 AND (s.GEO_AREA IS NULL OR s.GEO_AREA = u.geo_area) 
 AND (s.LOCATION_CODE IS NULL OR s.LOCATION_CODE = u.location_code) 
 AND (s.RANK_CODE IS NULL OR s.RANK_CODE = u.rank_code) 
 AND (s.LEGAL_ENTITY IS NULL OR s.LEGAL_ENTITY = u.legal_entity) 
 AND (s.BU_CODE IS NULL OR s.BU_CODE = u.bu_code) 
 AND (s.SERVICE_LINE_CODE IS NULL OR s.SERVICE_LINE_CODE = u.service_line_code) 
 AND (s.SUB_SERVICE_LINE_CODE IS NULL OR s.SUB_SERVICE_LINE_CODE = u.sub_service_line_code)
ORDER BY s.user_selection_name, u.sAMAccountName;
```

Here's a snippet with table variables to test it out.

```
declare @mw_users table (userid int identity(1,1) primary key, sAMAccountName varchar(12), country_code char(2), geo_area varchar(10), 
location_code varchar(5), rank_code varchar(4), legal_entity int, bu_code varchar(4), service_line_code varchar(4), sub_service_line_code varchar(4),
first_name varchar(30), last_name varchar(30));
insert into @mw_users (sAMAccountName, country_code, geo_area, location_code, rank_code, legal_entity, bu_code, service_line_code, sub_service_line_code, first_name, last_name) values
 ('EMP012010275','GB','EMEIA',   'GB001',63,null,null,null,'0201','Mark','Power')
,('EMP012011143','GB','EMEIA',   'GB002',65,null,null,null,'0101','Lucas','Wonderson')
,('EMP011904661','US','Americas','US001',64,null,null,null,'0101','John','Doe')
,('EMP013562598','US','Americas','US002',63,null,null,null,'0101','Jane','Sue')
;
declare @mw_user_selections table (user_selection_id int identity(1,1) primary key, user_selection_name varchar(10), COUNTRY_CODE char(2), GEO_AREA varchar(10), 
LOCATION_CODE varchar(5), RANK_CODE int, LEGAL_ENTITY int, BU_CODE varchar(4), SERVICE_LINE_CODE varchar(4), SUB_SERVICE_LINE_CODE varchar(4));
insert into @mw_user_selections (user_selection_name, COUNTRY_CODE, GEO_AREA, 
LOCATION_CODE, RANK_CODE, LEGAL_ENTITY, BU_CODE, SERVICE_LINE_CODE, SUB_SERVICE_LINE_CODE) values
 ('Rule1', null, null, null,   63, null, null, null, '0201')
,('Rule2', 'US', null, null, null, null, null, null, '0101')
,('Rule3', 'US', null, null,   64, null, null, null, null)
;
SELECT 
 s.user_selection_name AS GroupName, 
 u.sAMAccountName AS UserName,
 concat(u.first_name,' ',u.last_name) AS UserFullName
FROM @mw_users AS u  
JOIN @mw_user_selections AS s 
  ON (s.COUNTRY_CODE IS NULL OR s.COUNTRY_CODE = u.country_code) 
 AND (s.GEO_AREA IS NULL OR s.GEO_AREA = u.geo_area) 
 AND (s.LOCATION_CODE IS NULL OR s.LOCATION_CODE = u.location_code) 
 AND (s.RANK_CODE IS NULL OR s.RANK_CODE = u.rank_code) 
 AND (s.LEGAL_ENTITY IS NULL OR s.LEGAL_ENTITY = u.legal_entity) 
 AND (s.BU_CODE IS NULL OR s.BU_CODE = u.bu_code) 
 AND (s.SERVICE_LINE_CODE IS NULL OR s.SERVICE_LINE_CODE = u.service_line_code) 
 AND (s.SUB_SERVICE_LINE_CODE IS NULL OR s.SUB_SERVICE_LINE_CODE = u.sub_service_line_code)
ORDER BY s.user_selection_name, u.sAMAccountName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be

```
SELECT users  
FROM mw_users AS u  
LEFT JOIN mw_selections AS s  
  --ON clause would contain a pair for every condition:  
    ON (u.COUNTRY = s.COUNTRY OR u.COUNTRY IS NULL)  
    AND (u.AREA = s.AREA OR u.AREA IS NULL)...
```

Group name would come to you from mw_selections table.

Comment: I appologize for inappropriate styling and table names, but i am typing from a phone. Will de my best to correct later.